# What's the most Pythonic way to read in multiple lines while assigning a unique variable?

Tags: python

For instance:

```
    def get_values(input_file):
       f = open(input_file)
       key = f.readline().strip()
       value = f.readline().strip()
       name = f.readline().strip()
       password = f.readline().strip()
       return key, value, name, password
```

where the input file is just a txt with 4 lines of info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
key, value, name, password = (line.strip() for line in f)
```

Also, in your code, you don't seem to *close* the file after you've extracted the information. This could cause some problems. You can either `f.close()`, or use the [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement, which is generally considered more "pythonic".

```
def get_values(input_file):
    with open(input_file) as f:
        key, value, name, password = (line.strip() for line in f)
    return key, value, name, password
```

To simplify your function even further, we don't actually need to bind the values to the individual names, as we don't do anything with them in the function. We can simply use a list.

```
def get_values(input_file):
    with open(input_file) as f:
        info = [line.strip() for line in f]
    return info
```

Comment: This, but also do `with open(input_file) as f` which will ensure that the file is closed.

Comment: keep in mind this will fail if more than 4 line feeds are in the file: key, value, name, password = (line.strip() for line in f)

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools

with open('data.txt') as f:
    key, value, name, password = (line.strip() for line in itertools.islice(f, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(input_file) as in_f:
    key, value, name, password = [line.strip() for idx, line in enumerate(in_f) if idx <= 3]
```